# Trying to installing dual boot ubuntu over the w10 machine , black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

What I'm trying to do is just installing Ubuntu in a machine that has already installed Windows10. However, when clicking either Install Ubuntu or Try Ubuntu , i get black screen. If I disable UEFI in bios menu, ubuntu installation boots but in that case installation tool says that No Operating System installed is detected or something like this.

Could anyone know someting 'bout this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must install Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows. Otherwise disaster will strike.

Comment: Yes, i learnt that from other questions and tried to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode as w10. But as i mentioned above, I got black screen when clicking install ubuntu. I disabled secure boot, hibernation... whatever suggested in other questions. But still gettin black screen idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally able to solve my problem. I have been suggesting the solution for those whose computer has 2 GPU. Make sure that you are using your discrete GPU while trying to install ubuntu.

Comment: This will depend on which integrated and discrete GPUs you have. Please update your answer with CPU and GPU models.